# Is Ender's attitude shown to be wrong?

Tags: enders-game

I only know the *Ender's Game* movie, so please use the movie as context.

One of the first things we see about Ender is him defending himself against bullies. He wins, but keeps kicking the bully for way more than would be necessary for self-defence. In his own words he does this to not only win this conflict, but also to prevent any further ones.

In the end of the book,

> we have the genocide, with the question whether there was ever a threat to begin with. I think the message is that this whole campaign and especially the genocide, are on very questionable moral grounds. I think this is made very explicit by the reaction Ender shows. However, I can't help but notice that this reaction (genociding an entire race to prevent them ever harming humanity again) is very much in line with what we see Ender doing in the beginning (keep kicking the bully).

Is the intended message supposed to be that this behavior was wrong? Or that Ender's solution was right? Or do the authors just want to open the debate? Or does it show something about the character Ender? If yes, what?

Comment: The moral of the story is that when right-minded people fail to communicate, trouble happens. Ultimately Ender is merely a child and the tool of those around him, used as he's intended to be used.

Comment: I'm not sure a good answer can be made based on the movie and ignoring the much richer and directly related content from the book.

Comment: Just a note to say—please read the book. It’s so much better.

Comment: Never judge a book by its movie.

Comment: The movie is nothing more than an attempt to illustrate the book. It's also based on two books at once, Ender's Game and Ender's Shadow. Per word of the creator.

Comment: The question of whether a narrative is designed to show the readers that something is wrong is almost always opinion based.  Occasionally you'll have an author come out and spell out the moral of the book she / he wrote, but such cases tend to be exceptions.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Feel free to edit, I don't know yet how spoiler tags work.

Comment: I confess that I don't have the (right?) kind of abstraction to see formics as just an another developed species which should be saved. They attacked us first, and Humanity arranged to destroy them. I still think that Antics were **just a plague to be extermined**, and Ender did this very well, destroying the anthill just like I would have done to ants in my home. I readed "Speaker for the Dead" and during the read I was bothered by the tone of the text, as it obvious that the author himself wanted to portrait Ender as a person living incognito and ashamed of the blame of beeing a "Xenocide".

Comment: As someone who has only read the books and *not* seen the movie, I can say from the OP's description that this aspect of the movie sounds pretty book-accurate to me.  I can't speak to how good the movie is as a whole (mediocre from what I've heard, but I'll withhold judgment until I've seen it myself), but the events described definitely are in the book.

Comment: The authors created a situation wherein they could write the next book. In the movie, the fact that we haven't seen a sequel yet implies that the first film didn't do as well as they thought it would. I hope this answers all of your questions.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In-universe, the two are very much linked. I'm going to use passages from the novel, because even though many of the relevant passages exist in the film, some of the nuance is lost or truncated.

Ender was chosen by the International Fleet for Battle School *because* of how he handled the bully. I can't find the exact wording from the movie script, but the scene does exist in the movie. From the novel, when Colonel Graff interviews Ender after his fight with the bully:

> [Graff] "Tell me why you kept on kicking him. You had already won."
>
> [Ender] "Knocking him down won the first fight. I wanted to win all the next ones, too. So they'd leave me alone." Ender couldn't help it, he was too afraid, too ashamed of his own acts; though he tried not to, he cried again.

When Ender fights the Formics and destroys them, we see his reasoning - though he does **not** know at the time he is actually fighting them. He thinks he is just breaking a simulation. But Ender does explain a little of his tactics to Valentine before he goes to command school (in the film, this also exists, though I believe the conversation takes place slightly differently):

> "I think it's impossible to really understand somebody, what they want, what they believe, and not love them the way they love themselves. And then, in that very moment when I *love* them...I *destroy* them. I make it impossible for them to ever hurt me again. I grind them and grind them until they don't *exist*."

The novel is very much about the character of Ender, and if you read the entire Ender quartet (*Speaker for the Dead* especially), you see what the xenocide did to Ender. Ender very much wants peace, he's not an aggressive person, but he will do whatever it takes to win. He is very angry at being used by the I.F. Command (tricked, really), and you can see this in his talking to Graff before he leaves for Command School.

> [Graff] "We used every means we could think of to communicate with them, but they don't even have the machinery to know we're signaling. And maybe they've been trying to think to us, and they can't understand why we don't respond."
>
> [Ender] "So the whole war is because we can't talk to each other [...] What if we just left them alone? [...] Maybe they didn't know we were  intelligent life. Maybe-"
>
> [Graff] "Ender, believe me, there's a century of discussion on this very subject. Nobody knows the answer. [...] Nature can't evolve a species that hasn't a will to survive. [...] So if we can we'll kill every last one of the buggers, and if they can they'll kill every last one of us."
>
> "As for me," said Ender, "I'm in favor of surviving"

But what happens after shows the character of Ender, and I believe that's the real center point of the development of Ender's Character (major spoilers for the rest of the Ender quartet).

> Ender goes on to find a new Formic Queen larva and is able to communicate with it over many years. In the end, he does find a place for them to re-establish their society and no longer being 'extinct'. Ender sees this search, which takes hundreds of years counting all the time spent at relativistic speeds searching for a suitable place, as his duty since he is the one who caused the Xenocide. Through his writings, called *The Hive Queen* and *The Hegemon*, Ender brings awareness to the fact that much of the war was **caused simply by not being able to speak to each other**. And that is the central thrust of his work as *Speaker for the Dead* - to bring out the truth, and to make sure everyone is understood.

Comment: I think this captures the essence of the answer. The question of whether or not Ender's attitude was correct has kind of a split answer: yes, that is how you have to deal with enemies with whom there is no possibility of communication, but no, the Formics were not that kind of enemy. A key theme of the *Speaker* books is that when we judge that we can (or cannot) possibly find common ground with another, it says as much about ourselves as it does about them. The whole series is (at least partly) about humanity maturing enough to recognise other species as like us, and not as monsters.

Comment: All the Formics got was the result of their own attitudes. The ants in my home acts the same way. If they keep to a small colony and a few individuals, maybe I would not bother to find their nest and throw chemicals in it. But they keep growing their colony until the time they disturb a more advanced species. This is the law of life.

Comment: @mguima Firstly, the Formics *were* the more advanced race - humans steal tons of technology from them, including gravity manipulation.  Secondly, it's the **humans** expanding who encounter the **Formics** - perhaps they should have kept to a small colony and few individuals.  Then the Formics might not have bothered to find their planet and throw attacks at it.  Thirdly: from the Formics' perspective, they thought it was a proxy-war, with disposable 'robots', as a form of negotiation.  The idea of making **sophonts** fight was anathema to them - so they're morally better than the humans too.

Comment: This is a great analysis, but I feel like it elides the point very slightly - unconditional and absolute force is not an ethical response, BECAUSE you cannot know if the absolute elimination of your enemy is truly justifiable. Communication helps solve for that lack of knowledge and offers an alternative to extermination, but ultimately, extermination was portrayed as wrong absolutely, not conditionally.

Comment: @Chronocidal Yes, you're right, but... Objectively, I agree with your three points. But - sorry for the ants - I'm a human and I really don't care about insect plagues, don't matter if they are "morally better" than the humans. :-) I think that Ender was a hero and I fell sorry about him passing to the History as a "Xenocide". If I were alive in a future when Humanity finds out a similar menace, I would join the "delenda Cartago" side.

Comment: @IronGremlin I think the books definitely brought up the issue of ethics vs. pragmatism; ie. it may be ethically wrong to destroy an enemy because you don't know for sure that they are entirely beyond negotiation, but if the alternative is to allow yourself to be wiped out, then sometimes the ethically wrong option is the only one you can take. Therein lies the core of the conflict in Ender's soul; he knows why he did it and he knows the justifications, but he also acknowledges that it was wrong given what he now knows.

Comment: @anaximander The bully did not represent an existential threat to Ender. I will cede that there is room for interpretation regarding the formics (The whole thing is post-facto, Ender believed it was a simulation, so in my view really what he's grappling with the entire time is that he's been conditioned to respond to a threat with overwhelming and absolute violence, and that this is like, a bad thing), but with regards to the subject of the original question - the bully - the ethical framework of the tale clearly indicates Ender made the wrong call.

Comment: @IronGremlin The bully scenario is a microcosm - to a child of that age, being bullied forever *is* the worst-case scenario. It's less about "existential threat" and more about "unacceptable outcome". The IF could not tolerate the extinction of humanity; for Ender, allowing Stilson or Bonzo to bully him indefinitely was something he could not tolerate. Ender believes (himself, or from his training) that violence should be a last resort. That means you should try everything else first, but it also means that when you use violence, *it has to work*, because you have no options left after it.

Comment: @anaximander I have a very difficult time not seeing the massive subtext here - That conditioning Ender was wrong. To me, that is made extremely clear by the passage you quoted regarding "love" - this whole quote is an admission of a deep seated psychopathy. The story as a whole serves to illustrate the seductive and corruptive nature of violence and absolutism, that one tends to lead to another, and that when they meet it is the worst form of tragedy. Ender exterminating the bully was not a virtuous choice, which is why it appealed to the literal villains of the story.

Comment: @mguima: One bit in the books but not the movie: The Formics thought that _humans_ were the insects, and as soon as they realized humans were each conscious, they stopped fighting and left.  In their minds, the war was over, until humans showed up and started blowing up all their planets.

Comment: One piece of key information in later books that would augment this answer is the Hierarchy of Foreignness https://enderverse.fandom.com/wiki/Hierarchy_of_Foreignness The formics were at the time, Varelse: "they may or may not be sentient beings, but are so foreign that no meaningful communication is possible with the subject", where war is questionably moral. Later, they became Ramen, and war was no longer moral.

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks for your explanation, but, I didn't watched the movie. My first (and impressive) contact with Ender's Gane was done somewhere in the 80's, when I readed the short story in a Brazilian edition of Isaac Asimov's Magazine. I readed the book "Ender's Game" in a hurry just a few years ago, skiping some pages / paragraphs. I never watched the movie full lenght, only the teasers.

Comment: @MooingDuck You said: _as soon as they realized humans were each conscious, they stopped fighting and left. In their minds, the war was over, until humans showed up and started blowing up all their planets_ Oh, I'm so sorry for their innocent minds! (just kidding) That was the kind of war where it was impossible to just "realize" that the counterpart is concious, and so you just "stop" fighting and "think" the war was over. Their fault was their own naivety. They deserved to be exterminated, just as I do with the ants in my house. ;-)

Comment: @mguima: You've still got it backwards. _We_ were the ants. The better analogy is if you go out into the woods and start building a new building, destroying an ant nest in the way, then realizing the ants were _intelligent_. So you feel bad, go back home, then the ants show up with spaces ships and laser guns and murder you and your family. The morality is quite murky

Comment: @MooingDuck Well, in this analogy, I would have deserved my fate: I shouldn't have messed with those smart ants. But, once I realized that the ants were smarts, just going back home "feeling bad" wasn't a prudent option. If someone goes out and gets in trouble, sometimes this will have serious consequences, some of them may not be avoided just by returning home and hiding under the bed and hoping it's over. I readed all of "Speaker of the dead" upset about Ender's fate as a genocydal. But I understand that, in fact, author had the deliberated intention of portraying him this way.

Comment: @mguima: If you read the short stories as well, it reveals that Ender was celebrated as a hero, and Ender wrote the Hive Queen book specifically to make people realize that what he did was genocide. In universe, Ender created this image deliberately. So yes indeed, it was the author's intent.

Answer (score 11):

I think it's more subtle than that.

First, you can't really post-hoc judge battle decisions that way: you can only judge whether or not you did the best you could with the information you *had at the time*. Military battle decisions are, by definition, high-stakes choices made under duress with incomplete information. Not only are they not going to be perfect, they are frequently going to be awful, even to the point of causing outcomes opposed to the goals of the decision makers.

War isn't just bad because of the outcomes it generates, it's bad because even logical correct decisions turn out with the benefit of hindsight to be completely *wrong*. Was Ender wrong in the cold light of day? Yes. But that was not the circumstances under which he made the decision, and he knows it.

He also *knows* that he knows it, which is what creates the emotional tension in the story: even though he knows ahead of time that he's probably going to be wrong and deeply regret the actions he takes he understands that with the stakes and lack of information he simply can't *risk* it. N.B. this is also (as far as I can infer from the work) Graff's take on the Formics, and likely a big part of why he chose Ender. I'm going to go out on an even shakier limb to suggest that the author is sympathetic to characters embodying this logic even while rubbing the audience's collective noses in the abhorrent consequences.

For perhaps a clearer example of this, I'm going to reference another work, Batman v. Superman, Dawn of Justice. In this scene Batman is arguing with his confidant and butler Alfred Pennyworth as they discuss fighting Superman:

> He has the power to wipe out the human race and if we believe there is even a *1%* chance that he is our enemy then we have to take it as an *absolute certainty.*

Emphasis mine. Batman considers it unlikely that Supes is an enemy, but the unlikely outcome is simply unacceptable. Now, unlike Ender Batman is kind of using this logic to do something he wants to do rather than something he's loathes, but crucially *the logic still holds*.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just Ender, remember he's being manipulated by everyone the entire time. He knew he was being manipulated, too. He knew that there'd never be someone to come help him, and delivering a decisive blow isn't just his decision, but what Graff and others were trying to manipulate out of him the entire time. If he couldn't do it, he wouldn't have been chosen as commander.

It was everyone else's decision to commit genocide, the bigger issue for Ender was how he was being manipulated.